# what are the differences between data directives like .byte, .space, or .asciiz?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have seen the following directives but I don't know exactly the usage:

1. `.space`
2. `.byte`
3. `.word`
4. `.asciiz`
5. `.ascii`
6. `.align`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `.space` reserves n bytes of memory, without aligning. e.g. `arr: .space 100`
2. `.byte` store the n values in successive bytes of memory. e.g. `num: .byte  0x01, 0x03`
3. `.word` store n 32-bit words contiguously in aligned memory. e.g. `val: .word  10, -14, 30`
4. `.asciiz` stores string in memory with a null terminator. e.g. `str: .asciiz  "Hello, world"`
   Exactly like `.ascii` with a `.byte 0` after it.
5. `.ascii` stores string in memory without a null terminator. e.g. `str: .ascii  "Hello, world"`
6. `.align` aligns the next data on a `2^n` byte boundary. e.g. `.align 2` aligns the next value on a word boundary. On the other hand if n is 0 then alignment is turned off until next data segment.

For a detailed information see this [assembly reference](http://students.cs.tamu.edu/tanzir/csce350/reference/assembler_dir.html).

For more details about `.align`, see

- [Understanding Assembly MIPS .ALIGN and Memory Addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608845/understanding-assembly-mips-align-and-memory-addressing)
- [MARS MIPS simulator's built-in assembler aligns more than requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926448/mars-mips-simulators-built-in-assembler-aligns-more-than-requested) - `.align` in classic MIPS assemblers (like MARS) works differently from modern GAS and clang: in classic MIPS assemblers, it can put padding *before* an earlier label, instead of expanding to padding wherever you put it.  (`.word` and `.half` also align an earlier label, unlike `.space`)