# MARS MIPS simulator's built-in assembler aligns more than requested?

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-alignment, mars-simulator

I have the following data segment

```
.data
a:  .byte   0x11
    .align  1
b:  .word   0x22334455
```

Assuming that address "a" is 0x10010000, then the expected address for the word at b is 0x10010002, but MARS stores the word at 0x10010004, ignoring the explicit ".align" directive. By the way, I used MARS MIPS simulator (Version 4.5 on a MacBook Pro) to assemble the above code.

Therefore, my question is: Is this a bug, or is it expected that the behavior of MARS differs from SGI's 1992 documentation for MIPS assembly language, e.g. [Page 8-1 of this Pascal / Assembly manual](https://www.cs.unibo.it/~solmi/teaching/arch_2002-2003/AssemblyLanguageProgDoc.pdf)?

(MARS and non-MARS MIPS asm docs agree that `.align` in MIPS syntax takes a power-of-2 arg, so `.align 1` aligns to a 2^1 = 2-byte boundary.  Unlike GAS / Unix assembler syntax for some other architectures where `.align` = byte align, where an arg of `1` would be redundant.)

Comment: Related: [Understanding Assembly MIPS .ALIGN and Memory Addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19608845)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL:DR: MARS tooltips are misleading; you need to disable auto-alignment for the rest of the section using `.align 0`.  You can't *just* under-align the next word.**

---

`.align 1` does align by 2, that's not the problem.  e.g. try it between `.byte` or `.ascii` pseudo-instructions.

e.g. this source produces 0x00110062 as the first word of the .data section, just like `.byte 'b', 0, 0x11, 0` would.

```
.data
  a:   .ascii "b"
  b:
      .align 1
      .byte   0x11
```

And the `b:` label has address `2`, *after* the alignment padding.

(I have MARS set to "compact" memory layout, data section starting at address `0` for simplicity.)

---

What we're seeing so far does match the Silicon Graphics documentation you linked for their Unix assembler.  (Which is very different from how modern assemblers like GNU `as` (aka GAS) and clang work.)

That SGI documentation says:

> Advance the location counter to make the expression low order
>   bits of the counter zero. Normally, the `.half`, `.word`, `.float`, and
>   `.double` directives automatically align their data appropriately. For
>   example, `.word` does an implicit .align 2 (`.double` does an .align 3).
>   **You disable the automatic alignment feature with `.align 0`**. The
>   assembler reinstates automatic alignment at the next `.text`, `.data`,
>   `.rdata`, or `.sdata` directive.
>
> Labels immediately preceding an automatic or explicit alignment
>   are also realigned. For example, `foo: .align 3; .word 0` is the same
>   as `.align 3; foo: .word0`.

**This doesn't say anything about using `.align 1` to *under*-align the next `.word`.  Only that you can fully turn off implicit alignment as part of data directives with `.align 0`**.  Having `.align 1` override and under-align the next `.word` without having to disable auto-alignment would have made sense and been a valid design, but that's not a feature they chose to implement.

(Note that `.align 0` is special: aligning by 1 byte never has to insert any padding; the current position is always a byte boundary.  Since there's no reason to ever use `.align 0` for aligning a single position, the designers of the syntax could overload it with a different meaning: disable auto-alignment.)

**MARS does support that.**  (And *then* `.align 1` would do what you expect,  aligning to 2^1 = 2 without an implicit `.align 2` as part of `.word` increasing the alignment after that.)

```
a:   .byte 1
 .align 1
b:
 .align 0              # on this line or any earlier line
 .word   0x22334455

 .word   0x66666666    # this word is also misaligned; auto-align is disabled
```

data section output:

```
0x44550001    0x66662233    0x00006666     as little-endian words
01 00 55 44   33 22 66 66   66 66 00 00    as bytes
```

And yes, `.align` (explicitly or as part of `.word`) doesn't just insert padding at the current position, it inserts it *before* any preceding labels, right after the last piece of data.

You can of course emit whatever data you want using `.byte` or `.half` directives if you really want to avoid implicit alignment to 4-byte boundaries, without disabling auto-alignment.  You normally don't actually want that, and it will save beginners from having alignment problems in most cases.  MIPS is a heavily word-oriented ISA so there's usually little reason to have an under-aligned `.word`.

### The only MARS bug I see is usability: a very misleading tooltip.

It currently says *align the next data item on specified byte boundary: (0=byte, 1=half, 2=word, 3=double)*.  This seems to imply that you could under-align a `.word`.  And it's highly misleading about `.align 0` which actually disables auto-alignment for the rest of the section.

---

**This is not how `.align` works in assemblers that use GAS syntax (GNU `as` or clang).**  (e.g. see [the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Align.html#Align))

On my Linux desktop, I assembled your source code using `clang -c -target mipsel mips-align.s` ("mipsel" is Little-Endian MIPS, same as MARS uses.)

Then I used llvm-objdump to dump the .data section (with "disassembly" because that's the easiest way, although I had to clean up overlap from the b: label that doesn't start at a word boundary.)

```
$ llvm-objdump -D mips-align-clang-output.o         
00000000 a:
       0: 11 00                # manually cleaned up this line
00000002 b:
       2: 55 44 33 22                   addi    $19, $17, 17493
```

Note that `b` has address `2`, not `4`.  (This is an un-linked `.o`; when linked into an executable the address would be higher.  Statically for a position-dependent executable, or just at run-time for a PIE)

In GAS syntax, `.align` simply inserts padding *at that position* until it reaches an alignment boundary.  So you normally want to put such directives *before* labels, so the label address is aligned and comes after the padding.  There's also no implicit `.align` as part of other directives.

MARS's (and old-school SGI) behaviour sounds kind of "training wheels" to me, but I guess it makes some sense on a heavily word-oriented ISA like MIPS.  That would explain why some code I've seen on SO with `.asciz` followed by `.word` works without alignment faults for loads/stores to the word!  Still, it has downsides for letting the assembler calculate the length of a string constant for you:

---

If MARS's built-in assembler even let you do `msg_len = msg_end - msg` (subtracting labels from the end and start of a `.ascii` for example, like you would in GAS or NASM syntax), moving preceding labels could break that for a `.word` after a string.  (By including the padding in a length calculation for a loop over the string.)

But MARS's assembler sucks too much to let you calculate sizes at assemble time, so retroactively moving earlier labels is not usually a problem.  I'm not sure if classic MIPS assemblers let you subtract local labels at assemble time to get a constant length (e.g. `addiu $t0, $zero, end-start`) or not.  MARS doesn't, so this bizarre (if you're used to modern assemblers) "mis"feature doesn't usually cause that problem, unless you `la` start and end labels into registers for use in a pointer increment loop with a `bne` loop condition.

Hard-coding is dumb, and it sucks when an assembler makes you do it (by not providing good `label - label` features.)

It seems that MARS just inherited that misfeature from SGI's assembler (or wherever this design decision originally came from).

Comment: Regarding turning auto-alignment off, MARS' source just says _"This can be turned off for remainder of current data segment with ".align 0""_.

Comment: Thank you, but replacing ".align 1" by ".align 3" in my code in the OP does properly align the .word at "b" to 8-boundary. Doesn't this contradict with the thought about the .word and its implicit .align 2 directive (of MARS)? Or maybe MARS is aligning to the max of (default boundary, 2^the given argument of the align directive)? In my code example, the max is 4.

Comment: @Michael: oh I should have actually read SGI's docs; I assumed this was MARS training wheels, but it's actually inherited from SGI's assembler.

Comment: @user8396743: updated my answer yet again; MARS is behaving exactly as documented by SGI >.<.  But yes, `.align 3` aligns by 8, then the implicit `.align 2` as part of `.word` doesn't have to do anything because it's already at a 4-byte boundary.